# Extract data from xml to Excel (Python 2.7 )

Tags: python, xml, excel, python-2.7

i'm attempting to extract some data from a XML file and create a Excel with the information.

XML File:

```
<UniversalTransaction>
    <TransactionInfo>
        <DataContext>
            <DataSourceCollection>
                <DataSource>
                    <Type>AccountingInvoice</Type>
                    <Key>AR INV 00001006</Key>
                </DataSource>
            </DataSourceCollection>

            <Company>
                <Code>DCL</Code>
                <Country>
                    <Code>CL</Code>
                    <Name>Chile</Name>
                </Country>
                <Name>Your Chile Corp</Name>
            </Company>
...etc
```

Then I made this Code in python 2.7

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xlwt
from datetime import datetime

tree = ET.parse('ar.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#extract xml
invoice = root.findall('DataSource')
arinv = root.find('Key').text
country = root.findall('Company')
ctry = root.find('Name').text

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')

ws.write(0, 0, arinv)
ws.write(0, 1, ctry)

wb.save('example2.xls')
```

But I get this error:

```
arinv = root.find('Key').text
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

And i guess it will be the same with

```
ctry = root.find('Name').text
```

Also when I change the "extract xml" part of the code to this

```
for ar in root.findall('DataContext'):
    nro = []
    ctry = []
    inv = ar.find('Key').text
    nro.append(inv)
    country = ar.find('Name').text
    ctry.append(country)
```

i get the following error:

```
ws.write(0, 0, arinv)
name 'arinv' is not defined
```

then again, I guess its the same with "ctry"

Windows 10, python 2.7

I'll apreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to ask shortened questions - without yours bunch of context code. Probably you find a solution yourself when you carefully try to split out exact short question.

According to the docs, `Element.find` basically finds only in direct children. You need to use some XPath (look about XPath expressions in the docs) like

```
root.findall('.//Key')[0].text
```

(given with assumption the Key always exists, contains text and unique within a document; i.e. without validation)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, im looking in to learn more of phyton, so anything helps. My code extract the info from the children when the Top-level is `<UniversalTransaction >`, but the original has an URL `<UniversalTransaction xmlns="http://www.name.com/Sche/Unive/2011/11" version="1.1">`
and with that Top-level the code cant extract the code, it just says `list index out of range`

Comment: Yes, if the document defines a namespace (via `xmlns`) you need add it to your xpath `root.findall('.//{http://www.name.com/Sche/Unive/2011/11}Key')[0].text`. Or use namespace prefixes dictionary with the second argument `root.findall('.//myprefix:Key', {'myprefix': 'http://www.name.com/Sche/Unive/2011/11'})[0].text`